# Can't cast to IGxCatalog

Tags: arcgis-10.0

I've recently ported a stand-alone 9.3 application to 10. Every thing works fine on my development machine but when the application got deployed (Citrix) I get an error at the following line:

```
IGxCatalog gxCatalog = new GxCatalog();
```

ESRI claims it can't cast GxCatalog to IGxCatalog?

I'm at a loss. Since this only happens when running in the Citrix environment I'm assuming its a problem with the install, but what could it be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently GxCatalog needs to be created using the Activator.

Answer (score 2):

This is because "new GxCatalog();" refers to the class interface and not the coclass.  Change it to "new GxCatalogClass();".  See the class interfaces section at the end of [this topic](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Using_ArcObjects_COM_based_in_NET/000100000151000000/) for more information.